# Changing the colour of the points inside a single plot

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, plot

I've got a problem with python...

I want a to plot a bunch of points; in addition I want to vary the color of the points continuously. For example:

```
x = range(10)
y = range(10)
plot(x,y,'.')
```

The first dot dark blue, the second one a bit paler and so on...
As a first step I tried to pass a differing grey scale to the function, but raised the error 'could not convert string to float'... What kind of variable is passed? How can I avoid the error?

```
for i in range(10):
    plot(x,y,'i*0,1')
```

Thank you in advance for helping me out. I haven't found anything on the web but I think this would be quite handy for a lot of people...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `scatter` rather than `plot`:

```
x = range(10)
y = range(10)
plt.scatter(x,y,s=60,c=x,cmap=plt.get_cmap('seismic'))
```

[image: seismic_colormap]

The `c` keyword argument specifies what values should be mapped to color. I just used the x-values here, but you could use any array of the same length. The `cmap` keyword argument specifies how to map the values to colors. You can see some other colormaps here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

You can use a different colormap as well:

```
plt.scatter(x,y,s=60,c=x,cmap=plt.get_cmap('spectrum'))
```

[image: spectrum_colormap]